# The DOM is not updating after my post request with axios in React although the state is updated

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a very simple basic React application up and running. I can post and get data via axios and I can see in the console that when I post data my state is updated but the DOM does not reflect that and I need to refresh to see the change. Please check what I do wrong:

Here is my get method in componentDidMount:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    axios
        .get("dburl/posts.json")
        .then(response => {
        const data = Object.values(response.data);
        this.setState({ posts : data });
        });
}
```

and this is my post method for form submision. I am creating posts with title and content and show them in the screen:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {post} = this.state;
    const {posts} = this.state;
    axios
        .post("dburl/posts.json", post)
        .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        const newPost = Object.values(response.data);
        this.setState({ post: newPost });
        const updatedPosts = posts.push({title:post.title,content:post.content});
        console.log(post);
        console.log(updatedPosts);
        console.log(this.state.posts);
        });
};
```

And here is how I display the data:

```
render() {
    let posts = <p>No posts yet</p>;
    if (this.state.posts !== null) {
        posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
            return <Post key={post.id} {...post} />;
        });
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {posts}
            <form className="new-post-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    Post title
                    <input
                        className="title-input"
                        type="text"
                        name="title"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </label>
                <label>
                    Post content
                    <input
                        className="content-input"
                        type="text"
                        name="content"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </label>
                <input className="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I don't understand why it is not updating the DOM and the new post is not showing right away. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Update your state    `this.setState({ post: updatedPosts });` and after `const updatedPosts =`

Comment: Thanks . I don't know why I removed that line from there. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating your state wrongly, 
your code:

```
console.log(response);
const newPost = Object.values(response.data);
this.setState({ post: newPost });//this will update the state with new values
const updatedPosts = posts.push({title:post.title,content:post.content});//here you are
pushing the new values to the existing posts
console.log(post);
console.log(updatedPosts);
console.log(this.state.posts);
```

Desired code:

```
console.log(response);
const newPost = Object.values(response.data);
this.setState({ posts:  [...this.state.posts, {title:post.title,content:post.content}]});
console.log(post);
console.log(this.state.posts);
```

This way it will update your state after updating the posts array.

Comment: Actually coming back to the code for some improvements I changed it to similar of what you suggested as it makes more sense to update the state of posts rather than post. This is ow I changed it:
    const updatedPosts =  [...posts, {title:post.title,content:post.content}];
    this.setState({ posts: updatedPosts});

Comment: It does. Thanks.